# UIAlertViewController flickers/blinks briefly

Tags: ios

I'm using this swift code to display an alert dialog from a `UIViewController`

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onTestClick(sender: UIButton) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When the alert is shown from a view with a dark (e.g. black) background, it briefly "flickers" (appears white and then instantly change to a color slightly darker than white).

This doesn't seem to happen on other apps and the system OS.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Is there any other code being executed along with the `UIAlertController` presentation? Any view manipulation, etc? Can you observe the blink if you change the background colour to a white colour? Not sure how the colour can be related but let's try to investigate. I'd suggest chopping some code on your VC and see if the behaviour still exists.

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira No other code being executed and no blink if white background. Also does not happen if not animated.

Comment: Hmm, hard to guess. Can you paste your view controller code please?

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira I've edited to show to full code. On the storyboard there is a view controller with a single button.

Comment: Easy way to make a gif and show the issue using http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce what you are saying and I don't think you are actually doing something wrong. If you turn *slow animations* on the simulator (cmd + t) you will see the alert controller being positioned in the center of the screen in a fade animation. When the animation is in progress the alert controller has a white background (and this is Apple's code, it's fine) and when the animation finishes the alert controller has a transparent background which will change according to the colour of the view behind it. You don't notice anything when the view is white because white + white = white! :)

I hope that helps.

Comment: But other apps don't seem to have this problem?

Comment: Can you give me an example so I can check please?

Comment: The Facebook app - enter an invalid login. Could be just Facebook though. Instagram has the same problem.

Comment: I see. If you will, you can report a file to Apple saying you don't enjoy their `UIAlerController` animation code! :P